# How do measures of error or uncertainty change, when the underlying variable is transformed?

Tags: experimental-physics

If I have a measurement $A$ with uncertainty $\Delta A$, then what is the error if I do a calculation like $\frac{A}{\sqrt{3}}$?

Comment: To add to the answers, more generally search for error analysis.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if the calculation is multiplication by a constant, then you multiply the uncertainty by the same constant. That's assuming that "uncertainty" refers to something like standard deviation, rather than to variance: if it's variance, then you multiply by the *square* of the constant.

If it's addition of a constant, it doesn't change the uncertainty.

If it's doing anything fancy like taking a log or raising to a power, or including some other random variable or more than one observation of your existing variable, then it gets complicated: and as a general approach, one can run a Monte Carlo simulation to get a numeric answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'f I understand correctly the error should be (delta A)/sqrt(3). Then the percentage error would be that over the actual answer.